# How to display Images with uniform size inside a StackLayout

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I upload an image from the network and I want it to also be displayed as the image downloaded from the resource folder

```
 <StackLayout x:Name="CardsLayout">
    <Image Source="c0.png" Margin="10, 10, 10, 0"></Image>
 </StackLayout>

var card_image = new Image {Source = "http://f0242788.xsph.ru/cards_images/c0.png", Margin = new Thickness(10,10,10,0)};

CardsLayout.Children.Add(card_image);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the added rows are not expanding to fit the image fully and the image shrinks its width to fit (which is correct due to `Aspect.AspectFit`).

Try adding `VerticalOptions=LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand` to your added `Images` to stretch the row's height.

Answer (score 1):

you could specify the **HeightRequest** to get this to work on a StackLayout.

you could change like this:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="CardsLayout">
   <Image x:Name="Image" Source="c0.png" Margin="10, 10, 10, 0"></Image>
</StackLayout>

var card_image = new Image { Source = "http://f0242788.xsph.ru/cards_images/c0.png", Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 0)};
card_image.BindingContext = Image;
card_image.SetBinding(Image.HeightRequestProperty, "Height");
CardsLayout.Children.Add(card_image);
```